# time stamp user input in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I am trying to write a simple java program where user will provide two time input like start time "07:51" & end time "08:09" in command prompt. I wish to use a 24 hr clock to avoid AM/PM issue and once I get the input I should be able to find the difference between two time inputs in minutes. I need the minutes later to calculate something else. Now I am trying to use `java.time.*` package so somehow I can use `LocalTime` to capture this, but not successful yet.

What is the easiest way to do this in Java 8? Can I do it using LocalTime at all?

Comment: @brso05 Time zone unfortunately does make a difference because of daylight saving time.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do:

```
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse("07:32");
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse("13:40");

Duration difference = Duration.between(t1,t2);

long minutes = difference.toMinutes();
```

Comment: or directly the minutes via `long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(t1, t2);`